# How to change all Folder Icons to Show the content/Preview Image?

Tags: macos, finder, icon

The default folder icons are not helpful to me.  I'd prefer to see a preview image of the contents or first image.

I dont want to manually do this for every folder either, just set a global default.  How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done automatically across the computer, but there is a way to do this quickly to a group of directories:

1. Select the files/folders you want to change the icon of
2. Open the Inspector (Right Click -> Get Info) or Command + I
3. Drag a new icon

Using inspector will be best because you can select multiple files to change the icons of at once.

Also, as stated in this link, Apple will display file previews for some items by default.

Dynamic Previews Documentation: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201067

How to change file icons, as described above: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH13922?locale=en_US

Comment: Apple should fix this. Windows has had it for years and it is super handy and user friendly.